# How to extract the values from ParamMap in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using a pipeline and a Crossvalidator to do some parameter tuning in Spark using Scala. I get a `ParamMap` containing the best set of parameters, however I don't know how to extract the values from this ParamMap. Let's say my ParamMap is called params, this is what I try:

```
params(new Param(????, "maxDepth", "description")
```

however the first argument for the `Param` must be of type `Identifiable` and I don't know what to pass. Any help?

Comment: It's been a while, but have you found the answer? I'm stuck in the same problem. I want to feed `bestModel.extractParamMap()` to a new model object.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check all the values in your ParamMap :

```
params.toSeq.foreach(pair => {
  println(s"${pair.param.parent} ${pair.param.name} ${pair.param.doc}")
  println(pair.value)
})
```

Then to retrieve only one value :

```
params(new Param(parent, name, doc))
```

Actually parent can be a String (not mandatorily Identifiable)